# How do I disable a button before any fields have been checked?

Tags: vue.js

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, I am calling the function incorrectly or do the html tag have to specific for the disable to work? I am trying to disable the next button before any fields have been checked, I also only want one checkbox to be selected at a time. I can get the only one checkbox to be selected a time but this stop me from disabling the button cause I can't have the field be inputs.

[image]

```
<div>
    <button @click="handleCompanySize(100)">
        <CheckIcon v-show="companySize === 100"/>
    </button>
    <button @click="handleCompanySize(101)">
        <CheckIcon v-show="companySize === 101"/>
    </button>
</div>

<button :disabled="handleCompanySize" @click="next">
    Next
</button>
```

Comment: `:disabled` should be a boolean data property. Does `handleCompanySize` return true if the current company size is invalid?

Comment: @PeterKrebs it doesn't return true or any value. I also tried setting it so if handleCompanySize is smaller than 1 it returns false but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `:disabled` disables the button. So maybe try `:disabled="!(companySize > 0)"`. This will work even if companySize is null or not a number.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the definition of `handleCompanySize`.

Comment: @PeterKrebs `:disabled="!(companySize > 0)"` worked thanks so much :), guess it was cause companySize was null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple requirement and looks like you overthinked about it. You can use a computed property in the `:disabled` attribute which returns true/false based on the checkbox selection.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    employees: [ 
      { "id": 1, "text": "0 - 1" },
      { "id": 2, "text": "2 - 10" }, 
      { "id": 3, "text": "11 - 50" }, 
      { "id": 4, "text": "50 - 100" },
      { "id": 5, "text": "> 100" }
    ],
    selected: []
  },
  computed: {
    disableBtn() {
      return !this.selected.length ? true : false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uniqueCheck(e) {
      this.selected = [];
      if (e.target.checked) {
        this.selected.push(e.target.value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <h4>Employee Selection</h4>
    <table>
        <tr v-for="employee in employees">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="employee.id" @change="uniqueCheck">
            </td>
            <td>{{ employee.text }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button :disabled="disableBtn">
      Next
    </button>
</div>
```